# Is there any way to change the order of arguments?

Tags: discord.js

I'm working on a command that searches maps for the game osu! on the site bloodcat.com and I made a way to filter the maps with:

```js
.split('status=ranked').join('&c=b&s=1&m=&g=&l=')
.split('status=approved').join('&c=b&s=2&m=&g=&l=')
.split('status=qualified').join('&c=b&s=3&m=&g=&l=')
.split('status=loved').join('&c=b&s=4&m=&g=&l=')
.split('status=unranked').join('&c=b&s=0&m=&g=&l=')
.split('status=graveyarded').join('&c=b&s=0&m=&g=&l=');
```

Now someone can do `!search 'map name' status=unranked` and that would look for `https://bloodcat.com/osu/?mod=json&q='map name'&c=b&s=0&m=&g=&l=` but if someone does for example `!search status=unranked 'map name'` that doesn't work is there any way. 
Can I make the `status=unranked` at the end even if the user doesn't put it in the end in the command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this: first, check if the string of arguments starts with `status=`. If so, you'll need to switch them, otherwise, it should work as it's doing now.
In order to switch those, I would split the string with spaces, remove the first argument (`status=*`), rejoin that with spaces and add the removed part:

```js
function getQueryURL(argStr = "") { // argStr should be like "'map name' status=unranked" OR "status=unranked 'map name'"
  if (argStr.startsWith('status=')) {
    let arr = argStr.split(' ');
    let removed = arr.shift();
    argStr = arr.join(' ').trim() + removed.trim();
  }

  let res = argStr.split('status=ranked').join('&c=b&s=1&m=&g=&l=')
    .split('status=approved').join('&c=b&s=2&m=&g=&l=')
    .split('status=qualified').join('&c=b&s=3&m=&g=&l=')
    .split('status=loved').join('&c=b&s=4&m=&g=&l=')
    .split('status=unranked').join('&c=b&s=0&m=&g=&l=')
    .split('status=graveyarded').join('&c=b&s=0&m=&g=&l=');

  return "https://bloodcat.com/osu/?mod=json&q=" + res;
}
```

Comment: this makes my bot crash with the error mapname.join is not a function